# how to connect/link words in an string array using one loop?

Tags: c, arrays, string

i have an array with n words .. i want to attach the strings togther ..
for example if the array have the following strings: "hello" "world" "stack77"
i want the function to return :"helloworldstach7 " any help how i can do something like this without Recursion and with one loop and i can only use from the string library the two functions strcpy and strlen !!
any ideas ! thanks
I NEED TO USE ONE LOOP ONLY !

```
char *connect(char**words,int n){
int i=0;
    while(words){
    strcpy(words+i,
```

i saw many many solutions but they all use other string functions , where i only want to use strcpy and strlen .

Comment: Show how the array is declared.

Comment: I'm sure `'n'` is being passed for a very good reason. Is it the number of words, or the total length of all characters combined?

Comment: `strlen` can be used to tell you how much to advance the destination pointer in each iteration.

Comment: lauren, please provide a Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example (see: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Providing the necessary details, including your code, and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: i should declare the array by myself ! i can cal the function like this for example : char ss*=connect(words,7)

Comment: i am trieng to say that i would declare a local words array that includes the n strings i want to connect

Comment: It is necessary to prepare the area after joining. Is there room in the first word?

Comment: also i can't change the giving array that i declared !! i can do it but i will have to loop on every string to find it's lengh but i can use one loop :\

Comment: n is the number of strings in the array

Comment: Ok, the issue with the array is that a *pointer to pointer to char* is NOT an array. Depending on how the array is declared it may or may not be reallocated. Next, what storage are you going to use to return the concatenated words in? Unless you dynamically allocate in `connect`, you must pass a pointer to a block of memory to hold the result as a parameter. That, as a starter, is why a MCVE will help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

If to use only the two mentioned standard string functions then the function can look as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * connect( char **words, size_t n )
{
    size_t length = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) length += strlen( words[i] );

    char *s = malloc( length + 1 );

    size_t pos = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        strcpy( s + pos, words[i] );
        pos += strlen( words[i] );
    }        

    s[pos] = '\0';

    return s;
}

int main( void )
{
    char * s[] = { "Hello", " ", "World" };

    char *p = connect( s, sizeof( s ) / sizeof( *s ) );

    puts( p );

    free( p );
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World
```

If to use only one loop then the function can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * connect( char **words, size_t n )
{
    char *s = calloc( 1, sizeof( char ) );

    if ( s != NULL )
    {        
        size_t pos = 0;

        for ( size_t i = 0; s != NULL && i < n; i++ )
        {
            size_t length = strlen( words[i] );
            char *tmp = realloc( s, pos + length + 1 );

            if ( tmp != NULL )
            {   
                s = tmp;
                strcpy( s + pos, words[i] );
                pos += length;
            }
            else
            {
                free( s );
                s = NULL;
            }                
        }        
    }

    return s;
}

int main( void )
{
    char * s[] = { "Hello", " ", "World" };

    char *p = connect( s, sizeof( s ) / sizeof( *s ) );

    if ( p != NULL ) puts( p );

    free( p );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `strcpy`, you can also use `sprintf`. Each of the functions in the `printf` family returns the number of characters actually output allowing you to compute an offset in your final string without an additional function call. Now, there is nothing wrong with using a `strcpy/strlen` approach, and in fact, that is probably the preferred approach, but be aware that there are always multiple ways of doing things within the parameters you have given. Also note that the `printf` family offers a wealth of formatting benefits in the event you would need to include additional information along with the concatenation of strings.

For example, using `sprintf` to concatenate each string while saving the number of characters in each `nc` as the offset for writing the next string to the resulting buffer `buf`, while using a *ternary* operator to control the addition of a `space` between the words based on your loop counter, you could do something similar to the following:

```
char *compress (char **p, int n)
{
    char *buf = NULL;     /* buffer to hold concatendated string */
    size_t total = 0;     /* total number of characters required */
    int nc = 0;           /* number of chars added (counter)     */

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)     /* get total required length */
        total += strlen (p[i]) + 1; /* including spaces between  */

    if (!(buf = malloc (total + 1)))    /* allocate/validate mem */
        return buf;                     /* return NULL on error  */

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) /* add each word to buf, save nc */
        nc += sprintf (buf + nc, i ? " %s" : "%s", p[i]);

    *(buf + nc) = 0;      /* affirmatively nul-terminate buf */

    return buf;
}
```

**note:** each memory allocation with `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc` should be validated to insure it succeeds, and the error handled in the event of failure. (here `NULL` is returned if allocation fails).

Putting that together in a short example, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *compress (char **p, int n)
{
    char *buf = NULL;     /* buffer to hold concatendated string */
    size_t total = 0;     /* total number of characters required */
    int nc = 0;           /* number of chars added (counter)     */

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)     /* get total required length */
        total += strlen (p[i]) + 1; /* including spaces between  */

    if (!(buf = malloc (total + 1)))    /* allocate/validate mem */
        return buf;                     /* return NULL on error  */

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) /* add each word to buf, save nc */
        nc += sprintf (buf + nc, i ? " %s" : "%s", p[i]);

    *(buf + nc) = 0;      /* affirmatively nul-terminate buf */

    return buf;
}

int main (void) {

    char *sa[] = { "My", "dog", "has", "too many", "fleas." },
        *result = compress (sa, sizeof sa/sizeof *sa);

    if (result) {                              /* check return */
        printf ("result: '%s'\n", result);     /* print string */
        free (result);                         /* free memory  */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strcat_sprintf
result: 'My dog has too many fleas.'
```

**Memory/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block of memory, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/strcat_sprintf
==27595== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==27595== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==27595== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==27595== Command: ./bin/strcat_sprintf
==27595==
result: 'My dog has too many fleas.'
==27595==
==27595== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27595==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27595==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 28 bytes allocated
==27595==
==27595== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==27595==
==27595== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==27595== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have any additional questions.

---

`compress` **with a Single Loop**

As mentioned in the comment to MarianD's answer, you can use a single loop, reallocating your buffer with the addition of each word to the final string, but that is less efficient than getting the total number of characters required and then allocating once. However, there are many occasions where that is exactly what you will be required to do. Basically, you will simply get the length of each word and then allocate memory for that word (and the space between it and the next and for the *nul-byte*) using `realloc` instead of `malloc` (or `calloc`). `realloc` acts just like `malloc` for the first allocation, thereafter it resizes the buffer maintaining its current contents.

**note:** never `realloc` the buffer directly (e.g. `buf = realloc (buf, newsize);`), instead, always use a temporary pointer. Why? IF realloc fails, `NULL` is returned by `realloc` which causes you to lose the reference to your original `buf` (e.g. it will result in `buf = NULL;`), meaning that the address for your original `buf` is lost (and you have created a memory leak).

Putting that together, you could do something like the following:

```
char *compress (char **p, int n)
{
    char *buf = NULL;     /* buffer to hold concatendated string */
    size_t bufsz = 0;     /* current allocation size for buffer  */
    int nc = 0;           /* number of chars added (counter)     */

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {       /* add each word to buf  */
        size_t len = strlen (p[i]) + 1; /* get length of word    */
        void *tmp = realloc (buf, bufsz + len);   /* realloc buf */

        if (!tmp)                       /* validate reallocation */
            return buf;                 /* return current buffer */

        buf = tmp;         /* assign reallocated block to buffer */
        bufsz += len;       /* increment bufsz to current size   */

        nc += sprintf (buf + nc, i ? " %s" : "%s", p[i]);
    }

    *(buf + nc) = 0;      /* affirmatively nul-terminate buf */

    return buf;
}
```

**Memory/Error Check**

```
$ valgrind ./bin/strcat_sprintf_realloc
==28175== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==28175== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==28175== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==28175== Command: ./bin/strcat_sprintf_realloc
==28175==
result: 'My dog has too many fleas.'
==28175==
==28175== HEAP SUMMARY:
==28175==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28175==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 68 bytes allocated
==28175==
==28175== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==28175==
==28175== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==28175== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**note:** now there are `5` allocations instead of `1`.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: thank you so much but as i saied i am looking for a solution using only one loop !!

Comment: OK, I'll add a `realloc` example.

Comment: the time line ended ! no need any more for you to help me .. thanks anyway

Comment: Hopefully you found the single loop addition before then. Good luck with your coding.